# Firebase auth not return anything. Help newbie Here

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm working on simple registration activity. Users will send the data from registration page to Firebase Authentication but sadly it not returning any data. No error in the editor and logcat. I have followed all instruction from Firebase website regarding to how to set Firebase using Android Studio

Here my Registration Page

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class RegistrationPage : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_page)
        auth = Firebase.auth

        val emailReg = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.emailRegistration).text.toString()
        val passwordReg = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passwordRegistration).text.toString()
        val continueButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.signUpRegistrationButton)



        continueButton.setOnClickListener {
            this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailReg, passwordReg)
            sendEmailVerification()
        }
    }
    private fun sendEmailVerification() {

        val user = auth.currentUser!!
        user.sendEmailVerification()


    }
}
```

Here the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegistrationPage">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bluebackground"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/registrationTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Registration"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newAccountTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Account"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailRegistration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordRegistration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailRegistration"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/confirmPasswordRegistration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Confirm password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordRegistration"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameRegistration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Full name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/confirmPasswordRegistration"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Mobile number, eg: 0123456789"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameRegistration"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/agreementDeclare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:text="@string/agreement"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/policyPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="Privacy Policy"
        android:textColor="@color/linkBlue"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signUpRegistrationButton" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/termsPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="Terms &amp; Condition"
        android:textColor="@color/linkBlue"
        android:textSize="11sp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/policyPage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signUpRegistrationButton" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpRegistrationButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button_background"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/yellow"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/agreementDeclare"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here my AndroidManifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.haziqharis.myapplication">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".TermsAndCondition"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PrivacyPolicy"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegistrationPage"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".HomePage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here my gradle.Project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here my gradle.Module

```
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Not return any email and password
[image: Not returning any email and password]

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Have you tried Courtesy's solution? Does it work?

Comment: Yeah it's working @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

Add on complete listener to createUserWithEmailAndPassword method to see what it actually will return.

```kotlin
this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailReg, passwordReg)  
    .addOnCompleteListener { task -> 
        if (task.isSuccessful) {  
            Log.d(TAG, "SignInWithEmail:success")  
        } else {  
            Log.w(TAG, "SignInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)  
        }
    }
```

It might give you some clue why your solution fails.

Comment: It's working for me. Thank you !!